# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/DependenciesBlockVariable'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/DependenciesBlockVariable'

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the node_modules and package_lock.json, then re-install the modules.

```js
rm node_modules -r
rm package_lock.json
npm i
```